# sql - check if row even exist while update without extra query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
echo mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE stuff SET fieldd = 2 WHERE bla = 7");
```

It returns `1` when `7` exists in `bla`

But it also returns `1` when `7` in bla don't exists, why???? Is there a way to find out if the update was successfull/if this row exists without checking if this row exists with extra query before?

Comment: What DB API are you using?

Comment: You mean mysqli in PHP? I forgot to add it. Edited

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: But it won't return "successfull" when the row exist BUT fieldd is allready 2 right?

Comment: affected rows doesn't tell you if the record exists. If you are trying to update a column to a value it already has, affected rows will be 0.

Comment: Ok thats not what I need, I need 1 to be returned if the row just exist no matter if it was actually updated or not

Answer (score 0):

One method uses variables:

```
SET @found = 0;
UPDATE stuff
    SET fieldd = if(@found := 1, 2, 2)
    WHERE bla = 7;

SELECT @found;
```

A more formal way is to use `mysql_affected_rows()` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html)).  By default, though, this only shows if the row has actually changed.

Comment: It's kinda hard to understand how exactly to use it oO can you edit it as PHP code pls?